# global recover handler for golang http panic

Tags: go, gorilla

I want to create global err handler to send it by email.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    rtr := mux.NewRouter()
    rtr.HandleFunc("/", withPanic).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", rtr)
    log.Println("Listening...")

    http.ListenAndServe(":3001", http.DefaultServeMux)
}

func withPanic(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    panic("somewhere here will be panic, but I don't know where exactly")
}
```

How to make it global. It would be easy if I know where error will occur

```
if err != nil {
sendMeMail(err)
}
```

But what to do in cases when I don't know exactly where an error will occur? So I should add a global `recover`ish handler. But how to do it exactly I don't know.

## Update

I added `defer recover` to beginning of `main` but it never executes on requesting `http://localhost:3001`. So panic is not emailed.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            fmt.Println("Recovered in f", r)
            // find out exactly what the error was and set err
            var err error
            switch x := r.(type) {
            case string:
                err = errors.New(x)
            case error:
                err = x
            default:
                err = errors.New("Unknown panic")
            }
            if err != nil {
                // sendMeMail(err)
                fmt.Println("sendMeMail")
            }
        }
    }()
    rtr := mux.NewRouter()
    rtr.HandleFunc("/", withPanic).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", rtr)
    log.Println("Listening...")

    http.ListenAndServe(":3001", http.DefaultServeMux)
}

func withPanic(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    panic("somewhere here will be panic, but I don't know where exactly")
}
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can wrap your handlers in a recovery middleware

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    m := mux.NewRouter()
    m.Handle("/", RecoverWrap(http.HandlerFunc(handler))).Methods("GET")

    http.Handle("/", m)
    log.Println("Listening...")

    http.ListenAndServe(":3001", nil)

}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    panic(errors.New("panicing from error"))
}

func RecoverWrap(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        defer func() {
            r := recover()
            if r != nil {
                var err error
                switch t := r.(type) {
                case string:
                    err = errors.New(t)
                case error:
                    err = t
                default:
                    err = errors.New("Unknown error")
                }
                sendMeMail(err)
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
        }()
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func sendMeMail(err error) {
    // send mail
}
```

You can take a a look at [codahale recovery handler](https://github.com/codahale/http-handlers/blob/master/recovery/recovery.go) or [negroni middleware](https://github.com/codegangsta/negroni/blob/master/recovery.go) for more details.

Comment: e.Error() should be err.Error()?

Comment: fixed @eyeAppsLLC.

Comment: Very neat solution

Comment: `r := recover()` hides `r *http.Request` from outer function. If you want to access it in recovery block - better to change the name, e.g. `e := recover()`

Answer (score 5):

I believe that is what the [gorilla recovery handler](https://github.com/gorilla/handlers/blob/master/recovery.go) is for